# Bendixson negative test or an ellips

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Apparantly, this system of equations doesn't have a periodic solution:

$$x' = x(1-x^2-3y^2)$$

$$y' = y(3-x^2-3y^2)$$

We used in the Bendixson negative test in class so

$$f_x = 1-3x^2-3y^2$$

$$f_y = 3-x^2-9y^2$$

$$f_x + f_y = 4 - 4x^2 - 12y^2$$

I graphed an ellipse with an equation of

$$1 = (x^2/1) + (y^2/(1/3))$$

1. My professor said any point plugged in from inside the ellipse is $0$. I plugged in several points from the inside and $0$ is not received.
2. The sign does change as I plug in more points.

I'm confused on why this system doesn't have a periodic solution and fulfills Bendixson Negative test.